# GetChildByName is not working

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

i am having problem in getting child from starling.current.nativestage -
here is my code

`var temp:Image = Starling.current.nativeStage.getChildByName("ball"+turn)as Image;
trace(temp.name);`

the code "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."
am i making any mistake or what?

help me please
Note*i m noob in starling

Comment: What is happening? Do you get an error?

Comment: Could you provide more code so I may understand the context better? Specifically the variable turn?

Comment: Have you tried debugging ?

Answer (score 0):

nativeStage returns the flash Stage.  These are flash.display.DisplayObjects.  You then cast to a starling.display.Image via `as Image`.  This will always return null.

So, do you really mean the native flash stage, or the starling stage - `starling.current.stage`?

```
var temp:Image = Starling.current.stage.getChildByName("ball"+turn)as Image;
trace(temp ? temp.name : "temp is null");
```